# How to change (restore) only part of the xib file

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, xib, xcode4.6

I badly messed up 50% part of my xib that was responsible for portrait mode of my view controller.

The landscape mode part is correctly done by me. I don't want to lose that. But I want to restore the portrait part to what it was before I messed it up.

See the illustration below:

[image]

Entire hierarchy near Yellow box is what I want to throw away. In other words, I want this part be restored from my unchanged copy.

Entire hierarchy near green box is what I want to keep intact (from my modified copy), because I have made major changes to it, changes that works correctly. And I want to preserve them.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

**P.S.:**
I opened the xib in source (xml) mode but hierarchy wasn't very helpful. I couldn't properly locate the part I wanted to remove, and I was quite afraid of messing the entire thing badly.

Comment: What if you just duplicate the file, then modify each copy to be what you want.

Comment: I had some 100+ elements whose positions I changed. It is not easy to replicate that kind of change from copy-pasting each of them, since I didn't exactly know which place I messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I soon found out that the storyboard option of Copy-Paste is compatible with XIBs too. [Why not? Xibs existed before storyboards!].

Got what I wanted. Thanks for stopping by!